# Get the children of an element

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html like this:

```
<input type="text" style="size:3; width: 300px;" id="test">
   Shadow Content
      <div>test</div>
```

This is the hierarchy shown in my Safari browser. I need to get the value of `<div>`.

I tried:

```
$("#test > div") //doesnt work
$("#test *") //doesnt work
$("#test").find("*") //doesnt work
```

How do I find the div? Why the above codes are not working?

Comment: Can `input` have children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input>` element **can't have children**. It ends immediately after you close it with `>`. If you want to find this div in your particular code, try this:

```
$('#test').next('div');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$("#test").next('div').text();
```

You need to get the next div element.

**Problem**

You are trying to find div inside the `textbox`

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) as you are targeting siblings not children

```
$("#test").next('div');
```